# replace string with multiple array value jquery

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm having

```
 array1=["priya","reena","mathew"],
 array2=["teacher","developer","clerk"]
 my_str="hi{data} your profession is {data2}",
```

where I need to replace {data} with values from array1 and {data2} with values from array2. My final output should be like:

```
 final_arr=["hi priya your profession is teacher","hi reena your profession is developer","hi mathew your profession is clerk"]
```

I may get nearly 10,000 inputs, so how can I achieve this using jquery efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array_combine(a, b) {
  if(a.length != b.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    new_array = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      new_array[a[i]] = b[i];
    }
    return new_array;
  }
}

var combined_array = array_combine(array1, array2);

var output = [];
for(key in combined_array) {
  output.push("Hi "+key+" your profession is "+combined_array[key]);
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Using javascript**

```js
var array1=["priya","reena","mathew"];
var array2=["teacher","developer","clerk"];

var final_arr=[];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    final_arr.push("hi "+array1[i]+" your profession is "+ array2[i]);
}

for (i = 0; i < final_arr.length; i++) {
  document.write(final_arr[i]+ "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop on array using `forEach` loop . Make string pattern what ever you want and concat with looping value. Ans is based on assuming that your array1 and array2 lenth is equal .

```js
 
var array1 = ["priya", "reena", "mathew"];
var array2 = ["teacher", "developer", "clerk"];
var my_str = "hi{data} your profession is {data2}";
var fin_arr = [];
array1.forEach(function(index, item) {
  var res = 'hi ' + array1[item] + ' your profession is ' + array2[item];
  fin_arr.push(res);
});
console.log(fin_arr[0]);
console.log(fin_arr[1]);
console.log(fin_arr[2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array1=["priya","reena","mathew"];
var array2=["teacher","developer","clerk"];

var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
  result[i] = 'hi '+ array1[i]+' your profession is '+array2[i];
}
```